# What should be IUPAC name of given compound (see image)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, amines, organosulfur-compounds

I think the name should be **1-carbamoylpentane-3-sulphonic acid**, but the answer sheet mentions it as **2-carbamoylpentane-3-sulphonic acid**:

[image: 2-carbamoylpentane-3-sulphonic acid]

Can anyone please explain why the chain starting with methyl group is considered parent chain instead of one starting with amide?

Comment: The methyl group is part of the pentane chain. Therefore, the carbamoyl group is at carbon 2.

Comment: hint: your answer has neglected the methyl group entirely.